# WHERE clause on an alpha column containing integers fails in an integer comparison

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I can't see why the comparison fails in this sample code:

```
create table #a(a nvarchar(10))
insert #a values( 1 )
insert #a values( 2 )
insert #a values( 3 )
insert #a values('A')
select * from (select * from #a where a not like 'A%') b where a < 2
drop table #a
```

I understand that it fails with the alpha value included, as the conversion to an int fails, but why is it still attempting to convert the fourth row when I explicitly exclude it from the candidate row set b?  If I split this into two by writing b as a table, it works OK.  That is, this:

```
create table #a(a nvarchar(10))
insert #a values( 1 )
insert #a values( 2 )
insert #a values( 3 )
insert #a values('A')
select * into #b from (select * from #a where a not like 'A%') b
select * from #b where a < 2
drop table #a
drop table #b
```

...works.  What am I missing?  This is Azure SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Query optimizer is free to perform any optimization like [predicate pushdown](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/Predicate-Pushdown-and-why-should-I-care/ba-p/385946):

```
select * from (select * from #a where a not like 'A%') b where a < 2
=>
select * from #a where a not like 'A%' and a < 2;
-- the order of execution is not guaranteed so it tries comparison 'A' < 2
-- VARCHAR vs INT, INT has higher data type precedence, implicit conversion to INT
```

In order to avoid that you have to materialize subquery like in second example.

Unfortunately SQL Server does not support materialize hint yet: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32642629-t-sql-common-table-expression-materialize-option

Comment: Thanks Lukasz.  I'd have thought the brackets around the sub-query were a pretty strong hint, too.

Comment: @SimonSellick That would be the case if we have `/*+materialize*/` syntax and force to materialize intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

I test and find that these queries also works:

```
create table #a(a nvarchar(10))
insert #a values( 1 )
insert #a values( 2 )
insert #a values( 3 )
insert #a values('A')
insert #a values('B')
--query1
select * from (select * from #a where a not like 'A%') b where a < '2'

--query2
select * from #a where a < '2' and a not like 'A%'

--query3
select * from #a where a < '2'
drop table #a
```

According the document, `nvarchar` can be convert to `int` by [implicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-conversions).
[image]

You compare the `nvarchar` datatype with `int` datatype, SQL server will convert the all the "a" column value to `int`. But not all value can be convert:

[image]

But if you convert the `int` to `nvarchar`, the query works.

Hope this helps.